# How are database records identified in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have created a JTable with a DefaultTableModel that its populated with data from a MySQL database. I made the table cells editable and I've cought the event when the user changes a record and deselects the cell. I intend to update the MySQL database record that was changed in the JTable when this event is fired.
For now, I made it print a message about the change to the console:
**Value at (2,1) changed to 'Max'**
However, I can't figure out how do I know which record to update in the real database if I only have the new value and the row number and column number.

In web development, I would usually identify the record by the primary key and set the attribute value to the new value, how do I do it in Java?

Here is my code for the table part:

```
DefaultTableModel tModel;
tModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, colNames);
tModel.addTableModelListener(this);
table = new JTable(tModel);
@Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)e.getSource();
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
        String cellValue = String.valueOf( table.getValueAt(row, column) );
        System.out.println("Value at (" + row + "," + column + ") changed to " + "\'" + cellValue + "\'");

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should start by having a look at [Using RowSet Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html), if setup correctly, you can modify them directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would usually identify the record by the primary key

So when you add the data to the `TableModel` you need to keep the primary key as one of the columns of data in the `TableModel`

> I can't figure out how do I know which record to update in the real database if I only have the new value and the row number and column number.

If you have the row number than you can access the data in any column for that row.

In this case you would want to get the data from the `TableModel`, so you can use:

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(row, theColumnForThePrimaryKey);
```

Once you have the primary key you can build your SQL using the primary key in the where clause.

If you don't want the primary key visible to the user then you can use:

```
table.removeColumn( table.getColumn( ...) );
```

The data is still in the model, just not visible in the table.

Note: if you table is sorted then you will need to use the `table.convertRowIndexToModel(...)` method to get the proper row to access the data in the `TableModel`.